# Removing an entire tag containing specific text in the body with Python re

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to remove a specific tag with a string within it while leaving all of the other tags of the same type alone. Presently, I'm able to replace all of the tags in the document, but that's not what I'm after. Here's an illustration of what I mean:

Before:

```
<custom_item>
this should remain
</custom_item>

<custom_item>
string to remove
</custom_item>

<custom_item>
this one stays too
</custom_item>
```

After:

```
<custom_item>
this should remain
</custom_item>

<custom_item>
this one stays too
</custom_item>
```

I'm using this regex presently, but I'm not having any luck when I try to search for the actual string, which is test-false-positive, to remove:

```
regex = "<custom_item>(?:(?!<\/\1>|" + item + ")[\s\S])+" + item + "(?:(?!<\/\1>)[\s\S])</custom_item>"
file_content = re.sub(regex, "removed check", file_content)
```

This is my before and after:

Before:

```
some text
<custom_item>
  this one should still be here
</custom_item>
more text
<custom_item>
  test-false-positive
</custom_item>
some more text
<custom_item>
 keep this one too
</custom_item>
```

After:

```
some text
removed check
some more text
<custom_item>
 keep this one too
</custom_item>
```

Comment: [You can't use regex to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), just [use an XML parser](https://realpython.com/python-xml-parser/). That's what they're for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Andrej's answer is spot on. There is also [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) in the stdlib. But beautiful soup is nicer, if you have no qualms about outside dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, use XML/HTML parser to do the extractions, e.g. [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """\
<custom_item>
this should remain
</custom_item>

<custom_item>
string to remove
</custom_item>

<custom_item>
this one stays too
</custom_item>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

s = "string to remove"

for tag in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == "custom_item" and s in t.text):
    tag.extract()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<custom_item>
this should remain
</custom_item>

<custom_item>
this one stays too
</custom_item>
```